# Доставка сигналов только одному потоку : может ли часть потеряться?

Tags: c, unix, freebsd, pthread

Всем добрый день!
Если доставка некоторого сигнала разрешена только одному из потоков, может ли на практике быть случай, когда несколько однотипных сигналов (SIGCHLD) будут посланы практически одновременно, и процессор не успеет переключиться на данный поток вовремя, вследствии чего обработчик сигнала выполнится 1 раз вместо, к примеру, 3-х ?

Comment: хм, а если первый обработчик завершит процесс?

Comment: ну если процесс после будет завершаться, то вобщем-то все равно. но тут в первую очередь о SIGCHLD, т.е. можно ли таким образом потерять обработку завершения одного из дочерних процессов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, есть проблема. Если несколько сигналов SIGCHLD одновременно ждут доставки, будет доставлен лишь один сигнал. [Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398491/276994). Там же рекомендация по обходу проблемы.

---

Вот ещё, судя по всему, полезная информация по теме: [handling SIGCHLD with multiple children](http://markmail.org/message/wzg2iohvplf67xlq).

Comment: угу, я так и делаю. Я правда пока что такой ситуации смоделировать не смогла, и при завершении 5 потомков все их ресурсы освобождаются при вызове первого обработчика, а дальше 4 обработчика срабатывают вхолостую, обидно как то...

Comment: @margosh, а у Вас что, они (обработчики) в разных потоках вызываются?

Comment: @avp, напротив, только в одном. В остальных получение SIGCHLD заблокировано.

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю, откуда берутся 4 "холостых". По идее может быть только один. Или у Вас SA\_NODEFER в sigaction sa\_flags установлен?

    SA_NODEFER
    If this bit is set, further occurrences of the delivered signal  are not masked during the execution of the handler. 

Это цитата из FreeBSD man sigaction.

Насколько я понимаю, установка этого бита разрешает "рекурсивный" вызов обработчика. В кавычках, посколько это не совсем рекурсия, ведь не сам же обработчик себя вызывает.

Comment: завершаются 5 порожденных процессов, посылаются 5 сигналов, их обработчик просто пишет в пайп признак, что дочерний завершен. В другом потоке пайп проверяется, и если там есть этот признак, вызывается waitpid() в цикле, пока не вернет отсутствие дочерних. Затем снова проверяется пайп, а там - еще 4 признака... ранее я вызывала waitpid() по одному на признак, но теперь думаю, что если процессор вовремя не переключится на тот поток, где получение сигналов разрешено, то их туда прийдет больше одного, а признак в пайп запишется только 1.

Comment: Тогда все ясно и все нормально. Сигналы приходят раздельно. Все 5 обрабатываются. 

--

Если не хотите лишний раз вызывать waitpid, то можно попробовать запоминать сколько раз waitpid уже сработал и просто игнорировать лишние требования, читаемые из пайпа. 

Но (запрограммированный "в лоб") этот подход не будет работать, если сигнал "потеряется" (скажем 3 процесса завершатся "одновременно" и обработчик вызовется 2 раза). Некоторое время будут болтаться зомби. Ну, тут можно учесть время от последнего чтения пайпа (или  что-то в этом духе).

Поэтому на практике лучше не усложнять.

Comment: угу. если бы в пайп, как Вы уже когда-то предлагали, вместо признака кидать pid завершенного дочернего, вызвав waitpid() в обработчике, то этих допвызовов действительно бы не было, однако у меня в тот же пайп кидаются еще признаки завершения потоков, и признак прихода SIGTERM. Не знаю, вполне ли это корректно, но после предшествующих обсуждений постаралась свести к минимуму действия в обработчиках сигналов. Теоретически, можно вместо остальных признаков бросать в пайп pids, которые точно не могут быть потомками, 0 например, и принимать это за признак завершения потока, как считаете?

Comment: @margosh, не думаю, что несколько лишних waitpid катастрофически замедлят программу.

Я уже точно не помню все детали, но мне кажется речь шла о потоке (том что читает пайп), который пишет лог и может быть делает какое-то управление. Поэтому я и предлагал посылать ему pid (естественно, полученный где-то (видимо в обработчике) из waitpid) и не предполагал, что он будет сам waitpid вызывать.

А все записи в пайп лучше оформить как команды с расписанными форматами. Тогда эту штуку будет легко развивать. Предпочтителен фиксированный размер таких команд (проще программировать).

Answer (score 3):

Может.

В системе нет очереди сигналов, есть только битовая маска, приходящий сигнал выставляет там бит, при вызове обработчика (или действию по умолчанию) система сбрасывает этот бит.

Answer (score 0):

Не путаем понятия потоки (`threads`) и процессы (`process`).
Процесс может содержать в себе несколько потоков (тредов или нитей).

Если используешь сигналы, то он направляется конкретно процессу, а значит обработчику сигнала в этом процессе.

- [man sigaction](http://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=sigaction&category=2)
- [man signal](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=signal&category=2&russian=0)

Comment: @akalend, гениально... :) Вы вопрос читали? Он про обработку сигналов в многопоточной программе.